# Como chequear si existen parámetros enviados por POST a un controlador

Tags: php, laravel, variables

Tengo un formulario para dar de alta un cliente, dicho formulario tiene para agregar varios teléfonos o quitarlos (Esto esta realizado con javascript):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo sé que si envío este formulario, los input que se hayan creado con javascript se pasan como variables al controlador, el problema es ¿como chequeo cuántos nuevos inputs de teléfonos fueron enviados? Porque después en PHP tendría que hacer algo como esto:

```
'Telefono' => Input::get('telefono1'),
'Telefono' => Input::get('telefono2')
// ETC...
```

Ahora, si yo solo envió un teléfono, el segundo get de 'telefono2' traería un error porque, lógicamente, no fue creado por el JavaScript y por lo tanto la variable `telefono2` no existe.

Espero que se haya entendido este problema y alguien me logre ayudar.

Comment: Los select y los text field deben estar en un array[] y pasalos por $request y en el controlador lo tratas con un ciclo y los registras. No tengo tiempo para hacerte el código, si nadie te ha respodido mas tarde hago una respuesta bien explicita.

Comment: coloca el código de como agregas mas campos a la vista por favor

Comment: @Shaz gracias hermano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los inputs de los teléfonos deberían quedar con el mismo nombre y `[]`, algo así:

```
<input type="text" name="phones[]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="phones[]" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="phones[]" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="phones[]" value="4" />
```

Después con Laravel puedes obtener los teléfonos recorriendo el array así:

```
$phones = Input::get('phones');

foreach($phones as $phone) {
    // Haces lo que quieras con cada $phone
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar campos dinamicamente tienes el ejemplo acá abajo.

```js
var counter = 1;
function addInput(divName){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "Campo " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='campos[]'>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
    <div id="camposdinamicos">
        Campo 1<br><input type="text" name="campos[]">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Agregar Campos" onClick="addInput('camposdinamicos');">
</form>
```

Los campos agregados dinamicamente deben llevar un `[]`.

Y en el controlador los obtendrías de la siguiente manera:

```
$campos => Input::get('campos');
foreach ($campos as $campo) {
     $result = new Tabla();
     $result ->campo = $campo;
     $result ->save();
}
```

**Nota:** Donde `campos` son los `inputs` que en la vista tienen un `[]`.

1.- Uso el nombre de `campo` como ejemplo ya que tienes un `input` y un `select` y se extendería la respuesta innecesariamente.

2.- Cabe destacar que tu tabla en la `db` debe de ser una tabla relacional la cual la uses para agregar una lista de teléfonos para X otra tabla a la que ha sido relacionada.